# QML animations and effects

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

imagine that we have arrow image as here:

[image]

but we want to make from this image an animation:
[image]

---

### ***question***

This not very elegant animation was created from a set of different arrow images.
But i want to make same animation by qml. Do you know any components(preferably qml but if you do not know, you can advise me qt classes) with which help i can reach that?
 And another question, does it make sense from the point of view of performance to search any ways to reach that instead of combine set of images to gif-format?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updating based on new information that the arrow has a background.*

You need to crop out the arrow to an image file with a transparent background and have the background as a separate image.

From there, you can use a similar concept as below, but with the arrow growing.  I believe you will be able to find an image mode that fits the image vertically and does not manipulate it horizontally.  I would start by trying fillMode: Image.TileHorizontally.

Treat this as pseudo code, I don't have access to a computer to run this on at the moment.

```
Image
{
   id: backgroundImage
   source: "background.png"
   Image
   {
      id: arrowWithTransparentBackground
      fillMode: Image.TileHorizontally
      source: "arrow.png"
      anchors.left: parent.left
      anchors.top: parent.top
      anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
          SequentialAnimation on width {
              loops: Animation.Infinite
              PropertyAnimation { from 0: to: parent.width }
          }
   }
}
```

*Old answer for reference, before knowing there was a background to the image:*

QML very nicely animates size changes.  You could easily have a rectangle on top of your image anchored to the left side that is white and grows from 0 to arrow.width.

Treat this as pseudo code, I don't have access to a computer to run this on at the moment.

```
Image
{
   id: arrowImage
   source: "arrow.png"
   Rectangle
   {
      color: "white"
      anchors.left: parent.left
      anchors.top: parent.top
      anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
          SequentialAnimation on width {
              loops: Animation.Infinite
              PropertyAnimation { from 0: to: parent.width }
          }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank a lot. but if we have image-background, so we will see this white 
rectangle...

Comment: When we change the height or width of the image unfortunately a stretching effect occurs.  i've investigated Image.fillModed but  no one of them fits my target.